# React material UI autocomplete is not working with the formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this code snippet, which is written by someone else.

```
 <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                            <InputLabel id="combo-box-demo">
                              {values.type === "forAllCustomers" ? "" : ""}
                            </InputLabel>
                           
                            <Autocomplete
                              id="combo-box-demo"
                              name="customerId"
                              onBlur={handleBlur}
                              onChange={handleChange}
                              value={values.customerId}
                              options={agents}
                              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                              disabled={values.type === "forAllCustomers"}
                              renderTags={(value, getTagProps) => {
                                filteredAgents(values.type).map(
                                  (option, agentId) => (
                                    <Chip
                                      variant="outlined"
                                      label={option.name}
                                      // size="small"
                                      {...getTagProps({ agentId })}
                                    />
                                  )
                                );
                              }}
                              renderInput={(params) => (
                                <TextF
                                  {...params}
                                  variant="outlined"
                                  label="Customer"
                                  placeholder="Select"
                                  name="agentId"
                                />
                              )}
                            />
                          </FormControl>
```

Here we load bunch of `agents`. If user pick one agent, that agents `id` should set as the `customerId`.

Here we use formik, so  `onBlur={handleBlur} onChange={handleChange}` is controlled by the formik.

I tried by setting `value` to `values.customerId` But it seems not working and also I am getting an error in the console saying

> index.js:1 Material-UI: The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete
> returned undefined instead of a string for "".

How do I fix this issue?

Anyhelp!

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: Is `option.name` available at first render? Because if it's not, it will crash unless you provide a fallback value, such as an empty string

Comment: @VictorOliveira that error has gone. But still cannot set the value to the customerId

Comment: Is your component wrapped inside of a Formik tag?

Comment: @VictorOliveira Yes and customerId should map with option object's id, where do I specify that?

Comment: Could you paste your entire file on a jsfiddle or similar? Would be easier to help

Comment: @VictorOliveira Hi this is the sample code https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4riys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, the signature of the function `onChange` of `AutoComplete` is:

```
function(event: object, value: T | T[], reason: string) => void
```

However, signature of `handleChange` of Formik is

```
handleChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => void
```

The problem is that simply passing `onChange={handleChange}` will not do what you think.

See, if you put, before the `return` statement a `console.log(values)`, you'll see your `initialValues` object. However, a change in the Autocomplete will fill this object with strange `combo-box-demo-option-0` 1, 2 and so on. This is because how the Autocomplete component handles the combobox and the `name` and `id` properties. [According to Formik](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#handlechange-e-reactchangeeventany--void), `handleChange` will look for the name or id to operate, and none have the correspondence you want.

Enough said, to fix your problem, you have to use another method provided by Formik: [setFieldValue](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void)

Your Autocomplete should look something on the lines of:

```
<Autocomplete
  id="combo-box-demo"
  name="customerId"
  onChange={(e, v) => {
    setFieldValue("name", v?.name || "");
    setFieldValue("customerId", v?.id || "");
  }}
  value={values}
  options={agents}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name || ''}
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
  )}
/>;
```

You will not need the `useState` because you are not handling yourself any state changes. A regular javascript object will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the **agents** you are getting. There might be an issue with your **agents** data coming from API RESPONSE or from anywhere else. According to **Material-UI**, the parameter you pass to **options** should be in an **Array** but your one might be an **Object**.

Please convert the Data type of **agents** to **Array** instead of **Object** if it is not in an **Array** and it will work!

```
               <Autocomplete
                 id="combo-box-demo"
                 name="customerId"
                 onBlur={handleBlur}
                 onChange={handleChange}
                 value={values.customerId}
                 options={agents} //This should be in An Array
                 getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name} //Then access name
                 disabled={values.type === "forAllCustomers"}
                 />
```

Please check the Official Docs of Material-UI https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

Comment: customerId should map with option object's id, where do I specify that?

Comment: agents seem loading.Even in the AutoComplete drop down agents list is there.

Comment: Share your API response or whole data json output that might help. OR there might be an async request setting the values late before you can use them. There can be many complications!

Comment: Hi, this is the sample code https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4riys